# Replace between two characters in VI

Tags: replace, vi

I have a file like this:

14:rs546195859:105415517:C:T:AHNAK2

19:rs200396606:7676575:G:A:CAMSAP3

...

I need to replace the rs* between the first two : with "." in VI.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should find and replace that pattern

```
:%s/:rs[^:]\+:/:.:/g
```

Comment: Glad that it worked. Don't forget to accept the answer.